# Google Drive Web View returns wrong content-type

Tags: google-drive-api

Google Drive should be able to serve html according to this blogpost: http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.nl/2012/11/announcing-google-drive-site-publishing.html

But on my account I just get my html code between `<pre></pre>`.

I created a test folder with a test html file: https://googledrive.com/host/0BxVNvXP_dI5QTEstTEtmMXNkOFU/

Contents of the html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test 123</title>
</head>
<body>
    Test 123.
</body>
</html>
```

The [example](https://googledrive.com/host/0B716ywBKT84AcHZfMWgtNk5aeXM/) in the blog post has the following HTTP Response Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
status: 200 OK
version: HTTP/1.1
cache-control: private, max-age=315360000
content-length: 1724
content-type: text/html
date: Thu, 29 Nov 2012 12:55:22 GMT
last-modified: Tue, 06 Nov 2012 23:57:41 GMT
server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Nov 21 2012 16:10:52 (1353543052)
```

My page has the following HTTP Response Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
status: 200 OK
version: HTTP/1.1
cache-control: private, max-age=315360000
content-length: 96
content-type: text/plain
date: Thu, 29 Nov 2012 12:51:00 GMT
last-modified: Thu, 29 Nov 2012 12:50:28 GMT
server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Nov 21 2012 16:10:52 (1353543052)
```

The difference thus is the `content-type` header. Somehow I need to tell Google Drive my html is indeed an html. file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MIME type for a file is set at upload time. Did you maybe upload the file with a .txt extension and rename it? If you delete and re-upload the HTML file I bet it will work.

Comment: I created it through [shiftedit.net](http://shiftedit.net). Downloading and re-uploading indeed fixed it. I will contact the creator of Shiftedit so he can implement the correct MIME-type creation.

Comment: It is now fixed at shiftedit, files will get the correct MIME-type in Google Drive.